# Derivative of the inverse function

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> the function $f$ is 1-1 and differentiable for all $x$. the function intersect with the function $y=x$ at $x=x_0$.
>
> the derivative at the function $f$ at $x_0$ is $a$.
>
> 1. What will be the derivative of $f^{-1}x$ at $x_0$?
> 2. what will be the derivative of $f^{2}x$ at $x_0$?

I know that $(f^{-1})'(a)=\frac{1}{f'(f^{-1}(a))}$ so the answer for 1. will be $\frac{1}{a}$?

as for 2 can I say that $f'(x_0)=a$ therefore $2*f'(x_0)= 2a$?

Comment: Point 1 is correct. In point 2, with $ f^2(x) $ do you mean $ (f \circ f)(x) $ or $ (f(x))^2 $ ?

Comment: yes that what I meant

Comment: but which!?  It is like saying "did you want chocolate or vanilla" and replying "yes, that is what I want"  Please be more clear

Comment: Sorry, I looked at not as a composition

Answer (score 0):

1. 1/a
2. 2 f(x) f'(x) = 2 a f(x)... it is just only the derivative that is $a.$

Comment: Why is 1 correct?